# Does $\langle\psi|\hat{A}|\psi\rangle = \langle\psi|\hat{B}|\psi\rangle $ for all $|\psi\rangle$ imply that $\hat{A} = \hat{B}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

I've to solve this simple problem:

> Let $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ be two Hermitian operators such that:
> $$ \langle\psi|\hat{A}|\psi\rangle  = \langle\psi|\hat{B}|\psi\rangle \qquad \forall |\psi\rangle  $$
>
> Prove that $$\hat{A} = \hat{B}.$$
> Hint: expand $|\psi\rangle$ in some suitable basis.

I've naively tried:
$$ \langle\psi|\hat{A}-\hat{B}|\psi\rangle  = 0 \qquad \forall |\psi\rangle  $$

Therefore $\hat{A}-\hat{B}=0$ exactly.

But this seems to work ever with non-hermitian operators. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think the point is to show why $\langle \psi | \hat A -\hat B |\psi \rangle=0$ means that $\hat A-\hat B=0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, OP is right: It holds for not necessarily selfadjoint operators$^1$.

*Sketched proof:*

1. By subtracting $\hat{B}$ from both operators (and renaming), we may assume [w.l.o.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) that $\hat{B}=\hat{0}$.
2. Rewrite $\hat{A}=\hat{A}_1+i\hat{A}_2$, where $\hat{A}_1=\frac{\hat{A}+\hat{A}^{\dagger}}{2}$ and $\hat{A}_2=\frac{\hat{A}-\hat{A}^{\dagger}}{2i}$ are selfadjoint operators.
3. Use the [polarization trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) to show that
   $$\begin{align}
   \forall | \phi\rangle, | \psi\rangle\in {\cal H}:~~
   0~=~&\langle \phi+\psi | \hat{A} |\phi+ \psi\rangle\cr
   &-\langle \phi | \hat{A} | \phi\rangle 
   -\langle \psi | \hat{A} | \psi\rangle \cr
   ~=~&\langle \phi | \hat{A} | \psi\rangle +\langle \psi | \hat{A} | \phi\rangle\cr
   ~=~&2{\rm Re}\langle \phi | \hat{A}_1 | \psi\rangle\cr
   &+2i{\rm Re}\langle \phi | \hat{A}_2 | \psi\rangle.\end{align}$$
4. Deduce that $$\forall | \phi\rangle, | \psi\rangle\in {\cal H}:~~
   {\rm Re}\langle \phi | \hat{A}_1 | \psi\rangle
   ~=~0~=~{\rm Re}\langle \phi | \hat{A}_2 | \psi\rangle.$$
5. Deduce that $$\forall | \phi\rangle, | \psi\rangle\in {\cal H}:~~
   \langle \phi | \hat{A}_1 | \psi\rangle
   ~=~0~=~\langle \phi | \hat{A}_2 | \psi\rangle.$$
6. Conclude that $\hat{A}=\hat{0}$.$\Box$

---

$^{1}$We will ignore subtleties with [unbounded operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator), domains, [selfadjoint extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_of_symmetric_operators), etc., in this answer.

Comment: Why you use two vectors $|\phi\rangle$ and $ | \psi\rangle $?
The original question assume the same vector on both side $\langle \psi | \hat{A} | \psi \rangle = 0$

Comment: @skdys $| \phi \rangle$ and $| \psi \rangle$ both represent any element in the space, so $| \phi \rangle=| \psi \rangle$ is a more specific case of this proof.

Comment: Is the equality still holds in the cases which are ignored ?